# How to drop a row based on the condition of a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

- I am trying to drop the rows that contain `'CENTER'` in column `2`.

Works:

`BuildingNameContains_center = dframe[dframe[2].str.contains('CENTER')]`

Output works:

`BuildingNameContains_center`

Produces Error:

`dframe.drop(BuildingNameContains_center, inplace= True)`

`KeyError: '[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23\n 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41] not found in axis'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, instead of subsetting a dataframe and then trying to drop rows. Just subset the inverse of your original selection.

```
dframe = dframe.loc[~dframe[2].str.contains('CENTER'), :]
```